# Son changed password on iPad, need to recover Pages document

Tags: ipad, pages, password

My son changed the password on his iPad and promptly forgot the new one... He was working on a lengthy document in Pages on it and was hoping to recover the work since his last save to iDisk.  Will he lose this work if we reset the iPad in iTunes?  Any way to transfer the file from iPad to iTunes (it doesn't appear in the list of documents that we can transfer over)?

Answer (score 4):

Since necessity is the mother of invention, I've found my own solution...

Sync'd iPad with iTunes as usual, restored iPad to factory settings, then restored iPad from backup.

I feel like a fool for not seeing this off the bat, but if you knew this boy, you'd know what was at stake with him losing his work.  I have a feeling that he won't set anymore passcodes on his iPad nor will he forget to backup to iDisk.

Comment: +1 for backup success story. If I could, I'd +1 again for someone learning how important maintaining a backup is. Hm, I think I'll go Time Machine now.